# jquery get height of div dynamically

Tags: jquery, css

My website is divided in 2 columns.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="center">
           <div class="content">
           <?php
           $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '';

           switch ($page)
           {
              case "home":
                include("home.php");
              break;

              case "foo":
                include ("foo.php");
              break;

              case "bar":
                include ("bar.php");
              break;
           }
           ?>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar">
            <div class="content">
                 <?php include("block.php");?>
                 <?php include("block2.php");?>
                 <?php include("block3.php");?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#main {
display: table;
}

#center {
width: 720px;
display: table-cell;
background: #fff;
vertical-align: top;
}

#sidebar {
width: 280px;
display: table-cell;
background: #f1f1f1;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

I would take the size of the div #sidebar or #center whenever I change pages index.php?page=foo or index.php?page=bar, etc.. but the result is always the same

JS

```
$(function() {

var sidebar = $('#sidebar').css("height");
var center = $('#center').css("height");
console.log("center = " + center + " sidebar = " + sidebar);

/* not work 
$( window ).on("resize", function() {
   sidebar = $('#sidebar').css("height");
   center = $('#center').css("height");
   console.log("center = " + center + " sidebar = " + sidebar);
});*/

});

console.log --> center = 1414px sidebar = 0px
```

EDIT - If I try with .height()

```
var sidebar = $('#sidebar').height();
var center = $('#center').height();
console.log("center = " + center + " sidebar = " + sidebar);

console.log --> center = 1414 sidebar = -10
```

How could I properly get the height of my div?
Thank you
Grazie

Comment: you can use jquery height() function  $('#sidebar').height();

Comment: You dedicate some time to write this question. Why you don't just google 'how to get the height of an element with jquery?'. Is the first result.

Comment: @AlexChar _ i googled and the solutions not resolve my problem :-)

Comment: If none of the below answers won't work for you using `.height()` etc then I will remove my comment :)

Comment: It should be a simple thing, but in my case I always return the same value. Maybe because I use the table-cells?

Answer (score 4):

Jquery provides you with a function `height()`. 
You can use

```
$('elem').height();
```

to find the  height of an element

Visit here for more info [jquery height function](https://api.jquery.com/height/)

jQuery also provides functions like `outerHeight()` and `innerHeight()`, you can use them according to your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

`height()` - returns the height of element excludes padding, border and margin.

`.innerHeight()` - returns the height of element includes padding but excludes border and margin.

`.outerHeight()` - returns the height of the div including border but excludes margin.

`.outerHeight(true)` - returns the height of the div including margin.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to constantly get the height of a div when the window resizes, I would recommend using the resize event in jQuery.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    console.log($('#sidebar').height()); 
});
```

Also, the height function of an element gives you the height, which replaces the css property in your case.

```
$('#foo').height()
```